# Attitude determination during launch and landing

Tags: attitude-determination-and-control, sensors

Rockets contain accelerometers and gyroscopes to measure changes in velocity and angular rates.

Gyroscopes detect changes of the orientation in space (=attitude). You can integrate these changes to get the cumulative change in attitude and given one knows the initial attitude, the attitude can be estimated. But, gyros do not measure attitude. Bias and noise will accumulate and thus after some time the attitude estimate won't be accurate at all.

If you are not accelerating (i.e. standing on the ground), accelerometers can be used as inclinometers to determine the vector of the gravitational force, or less complicated, the downward direction. Quite often gyros and accelerometers are thus used in combination (via sensor fusion, e.g. complementary filter) to determine attitude.

But:
In free fall (e.g. in a rocket after booster burnout), the accelerometer cannot be used to determine the downward direction. The accelerometer would measure an accerleration opposing the drag force. Thus, the accelerometer can't be used to determine absolute attitude in free fall. (More general it can't determine the vector of the gravitational force if the acceleration is not known).

Once in orbit, sun sensors and star trackers are used but I don't think they would work during ascent or descent.

For rockets at launch and landing (think Falcon 9) I suppose it is quite important to estimate attitude. To counter error buildup of gyros some absolute attitude sensor would be needed.

So, my question is:
How do NASA or SpaceX or even missiles measure **absolute** attitude during launch or landing? Which sensors are being used?

I'd be glad about any responses.

Comment: The drift rate of high quality inertial navigation gyroscopes is very small, typically less than 0.01° per hour. Thus it doesn't seem like much of a problem during launch, though the high accelerations probably increase disturbances.

Comment: This is a good question but will get few responses for modern vehicles. The problem is that the technology used for launch and landing can also be used by other countries to make their missiles more accurate. In addition, SpaceX is very protective of their intellectual property. The combination of possibly going to jail and possibly losing ones life savings are enough to prevent people who might know the answer from providing an answer.

Comment: GPS is a thing.  Other options are radar, lidar, and optical (camera) tracking systems - either onboard or at a tracking station.

Comment: @jpa Thanks. Wow, did not know that some gyros are that good.

Comment: @DavidHammen : Thanks, makes sense.

Comment: @Wyck: Thanks, how would you use GPS, radar or lidar to determine orientation?

Comment: @DavidHammen  Do you know, which sensors are used during unmanned landing on the moon or Mars? It's basically the same problem and knowing the atttitude relative to the ground is essential.

Comment: Non-MEMS gyroscopes are really quite accurate nowadays. For example https://aerospace.honeywell.com/us/en/products-and-services/product/hardware-and-systems/sensors/gg1320an-digital-ring-laser-gyroscope has 0.004 deg/hour and 22 G acceleration limit. The [gyroscope on Gravity Probe B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_moment) measured 10^-7 degrees per year in 0 G environment.

Comment: Lidar can scan for features on the ground and match to known features of the topography -- same with camera systems.  (I thought you asked about absolute *altitude* -- oops, my bad, I misread)  Gyros and accelerometers measure relative orientation.  Magnetometers can give an absolute orientation, provided you have mapped good baseline field data but it's fussy.  Model rocketry uses a secret sauce hybrid of absolute and relative sensors, mag, accel, grav, and gyros.  It's usually acceptable use a gyro provided you don't do acrobatics.

Comment: @Wyck Thanks! Sorry for the missunderstanding, but I don't know the difference between attitude (not altitude) and orientation -- is there any? 
I was thinking of vertical landing rockets or UAV quadcopters being dropped from -- say -- 1 km height and a random, unknown attitutde having to land autonomously.

Comment: @Wyck A human pilot would use the optical information (horizon, sun, angles to of certain points on the ground, and changes thereof) to land. Which sensors do you think would work best for a  light UAV besides a camera? Would a star tracker work at that height?

Comment: Attitude and orientation are the same.  Attitude is an aviation word, usually talking about pitch/yaw/roll relative to local vertical or relative to motion (which itself can be relative to the air or the ground).  Orientation: which way you're turned - without translation (position).  Most UAVs have GPS and a couple of IMU packages (redundancy is your friend!)  You can search the web for IMUs for drones.  Camera or lidar vision systems help the most near the ground (landing) where GPS is not accurate enough.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a historical answer, the space shuttle used its Inertial Measurement Units (IMUs) and Rate Gyro Assemblies (RGAs) to determine attitude during ascent.

> The function of the attitude processor is to derive attitude related data for several user principal functions. ...
>
> Attitude Processor is structured to derive the vehicle attitude quaternion, using a selected IMU, at a low rate, 1.04 Hz, and to propagate the attitude by integrating a quaternion differential equation, driven by selected, prefiltered RGA outputs at a high rate, 12.5 Hz. There are some users, namely flight control, that require the attitude quaternion at 12.5 Hz, so that is why the RGAs (SRB RGA's) are used to propagate the attitude quaternion.

[image]

Source: [Shuttle/JSC GNC ASC 2102 Ascent Guidance and Navigation and Flight Control Workbook](https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/JSC%20GNC%20ASC%202102%20Ascent%20Guidance%20and%20Navigation%20and%20Flight%20Control%20Workbook.pdf) Chapter 3.3 ASCENT FLIGHT CONTROL

The IMUs were "stable platforms" described as follows:

> There are three IMUs on the orbiter. Each
> contains three accelerometers and two two-axis
> gyros mounted on an inertially stabilized four-gimbal platform. The IMUs provide inertial attitude and velocity data to the GNC software
> functions.

The Rate Gyro Assemblies are described as follows:

> The orbiter has four RGAs. Each RGA contains
> three identical single-degree-of-freedom rate
> gyros so that each gyro senses rotation about
> one of the vehicle axes. Thus, each RGA
> includes one gyro sensing roll rate (about the X
> axis), one gyro sensing pitch rate (about the Y
> axis), and one gyro sensing yaw rate (about the
> Z axis). These rates are the primary feedback to
> the FCS during ascent, entry, insertion, and
> deorbit.

Additional RGAs were mounted in the Solid Rocket Booster forward skirts.

These last two quotes are from the [Shuttle Crew Operations Manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any idea about more recent rockets, like SpaceX Falcon 9? I think, landing would require quite accurate atttitude.

Comment: Most (all?) recent vehicles do not use the Apollo era / Shuttle era concept of an inertially stabilized platform. In addition, there are rate gyros that much, much smaller, much much cheaper, and much less noisy than the Shuttle-era rate gyros.

Answer (score 5):

Another good @OrganicMarble answer to this question is [What sensors or combination of sensors do rockets use during takeoff for their orientation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/29537)

Adding my own experience with other systems, star trackers are a lot more useful than you give them credit.  They were already quite good 30 years ago, and they keep getting better all the time.  One reason that even old ones were very helpful is in many applications, you don't actually need to know attitude to better than the gyros can do during the first stage of launch.  Once you're in space and stop vibrating so much, you can look around, and figure out where you actually are, and are pointing.  When you compare that to your [Inertial Navigation System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_navigation_system) (INS)'s filter estimate, you can *solve for* the biases in the [Inertial Measurement Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_measurement_unit) (IMU), and use that to improve INS performance for the rest of the flight, as well as retroactively re-estimate where exactly you were before then.  The job of the first stage is to get you *close to* your desired orbit, not into it exactly --- that's what stage two is for, to make a small course correction from wherever you ended up to wherever you wanted to be.  The amount of wiggle room depends on your mission requirements, which drives how good your IMU and other sensors need to be, and thus how much they cost (and weigh!).

On landing, since you're slowing down and getting closer to the surface, you can use traditional airplane sensors like radar altimeters, radio navigation beacons, airspeed and pressure indicators, etc.  These generally work better for landing trajectories than they do for launch trajectories.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So, for launch, the IMU is sufficient until you get into orbit.
Do you have any idea about landing? (like Falcon 9)

Comment: Thanks! I knew it sounded familiar!

Comment: I couldn't find the meaning of INS by Googling. (I did find that IMU is inertial measurement unit.)

Comment: @WaterMolecule oh, sorry!  Inertial Navigation System -- the combination of the IMU sensors with the software that interprets the data.

Answer (score 0):

> But: In free fall (e.g. in a rocket after booster burnout), the accelerometer cannot be used to determine the downward direction. The accelerometer would measure an accerleration opposing the drag force. Thus, the accelerometer can't be used to determine absolute attitude in free fall. (More general it can't determine the vector of the gravitational force if the acceleration is not known).

Even before burnout, you can't simply integrate acceleration to determine the trajectory. What an accelerometer tells you is the rate of change of your trajectory relative to a free fall trajectory. So, the machinery keeps track of what the free fall trajectory is and adjusts according to the accelerometer readings. In vacuum after burnout, the rocket will continue to follow a free fall trajectory. So, you may determine the altitude.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I meant attitude = orientation in space, not altitude.